# Open VBA window with macro

Tags: excel, vba, editor

I'm currently working on a vba tool in excel with its own UI. Usualy I don't need the VBA window while using it.

But sometimes I want to open the VBA window to make some changes without closing the UI (Alt + F11 doesn't work at that point). So I'm thinking about a button that opens the VBA window. Is there any command that opens it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something I use all the time.

This code has been "tuned" for the size of my laptop screen.  Running it gets **both** the VBE window and the application window open side-by-side:

```
Sub dual()
    Dim h As Long
    With Application
        .WindowState = xlMaximized
        x = Application.ActiveWindow.Width \ 2
        h = Application.ActiveWindow.Height
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .Left = 545
        .Height = 550
        .Width = x * 0.9
        .Top = 0
        With .VBE.MainWindow
            .Width = 1.4 * x
            .Left = 0
            .Top = 0
            .Height = 740
            .WindowState = vbext_ws_Normal
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! At first I had an Error (1104) but after activating the "Trust access to Visual Basic Project " in the settings it all works fine! =)

Comment: @ostergloekchen  Great! ..................did you have to adjust the constants very much ??

Comment: No it was easy, i just used the current values while it was maximized!